# What dos the QVariant(QString, “”) of property mean in The Property System?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

The QObject subclass has a function tha it return the object of QMetaObject. The function is metaObject(). I use this method to get it:

```
    MyObject *myObject_1=new MyObject;
   const QMetaObject *metaobject=myObject_1->metaObject();
```

When you use this code it will print something like this.

Object.h

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class MyObject:public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   MyObject(QObject *parent=0):QObject(parent){

   }
};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QMetaProperty>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MyObject *myObject_1=new MyObject;
   const QMetaObject *metaobject=myObject_1->metaObject();
   for(int i=0;i<metaobject->propertyCount();i++){
       QMetaProperty metaproperty=metaobject->property(i);
       qDebug()<<myObject_1->property(metaproperty.name());
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Print the result:

[image]

When you use this code it will print something like this.

Object.h

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class MyObject:public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(Priority priority READ priority WRITE setPriority)
public:
   enum Priority{One,Two,Three};
   Q_ENUM(Priority)
   MyObject(QObject *parent=0):QObject(parent){

   }
   void setPriority(Priority priority){
       m_priority=priority;
   }

   Priority priority()const{
       return m_priority;
   }
private:
   Priority m_priority;
};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMetaObject>
#include <QMetaProperty>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MyObject *myObject_1=new MyObject;
   myObject_1->setProperty("priority","Two");
   const QMetaObject *metaobject=myObject_1->metaObject();
   for(int i=0;i<metaobject->propertyCount();i++){
       QMetaProperty metaproperty=metaobject->property(i);
       qDebug()<<myObject_1->property(metaproperty.name());
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Print the result

[image]

The question is why myObject_1 has a property that is QVariant(QString,“”)?
What dos the QVariant(QString, “”) of property mean in The Property System ?

View the breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your images of text [aren't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  They can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and don't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2):

You have printed the property from base class - `QObject`.
Use `propertyOffset` to show only properties for your derived class:

```
  //                          \/ 
  for(int i=metaobject->propertyOffset();i<metaobject->propertyCount();i++){
       QMetaProperty metaproperty=metaobject->property(i);
       qDebug()<<myObject_1->property(metaproperty.name());
   }
```

This property `QVariant(QString,“”)` is object name of base class.